# Commitment Level

Tags: solana, solana-cli, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I've written a basic rpc client which polls the state of an Solana account to look for a specific condition (i.e. a unique int64 Id being written to it). When the condition arises, I call a smart contract which takes the same account as a mutable argument.

Before doing anything, the program checks for the same condition. However this check fails. I understand we're dealing with a distributed system and that state maybe inconsistent for a period of time, but I can repeatedly call for over 30 secs and it fails each time, before ultimately succeeding.

I've read about the concept of [commitment levels](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment) but always assumed the account state passed into the smart contract would be the latest state of the world (i.e. processed)? What I appear to be observing is it's more like the finalised state.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be going on here?

I will try and come up with a minimal code example to demonstrate the problem but just wanted to ask the question first, to see if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So if you look at the docs you linked, `processed` has a note:

`the block may still be skipped by the cluster`

This is a very important note if you're only looking for account state changes and don't want some that may be false. There's a number of reasons that a slot can be skipped, or a transaction could be rejected by the cluster.

If any of the above happens, then the account state that is accepted by the cluster as a whole may not be reflected in `processed`, but `finalized`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end my specific problem came down to pre-flight checks using the 'finalized' commitment level when my logic for polling the account was using 'confirmed'. Modifying the `preflightCommitment` argument on `sendTransaction` fixed the problem for me.